# Why my NAT setup is not working?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, openvpn, nat

For some reason, tcpdump sees packets on `tun0` interface, but does not see them on the `eth0` interface.

I have an OpenVPN server, which I used to access Github from a machine that is not able to connect to it directly. OpenVPN was set up to push github routes to clients:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert cloud.crt
key cloud.key
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

# github.com
push "route 192.30.253.112 255.255.255.255"
push "route 192.30.253.113 255.255.255.255"

keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

I added NAT on the server via iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

(I also tried an alternative version - `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 82.196.2.80`, result was the same)

So I see packets on `tun0` interface:

```
$ tcpdump -n -i tun0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
06:37:47.936890 IP 10.8.0.6.58816 > 192.30.253.112.80: Flags [S], seq 1523900495, win 29200, options [mss 1366,sackOK,TS val 3602297008 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
06:37:48.960336 IP 10.8.0.6.58816 > 192.30.253.112.80: Flags [S], seq 1523900495, win 29200, options [mss 1366,sackOK,TS val 3602298033 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

But no packets on `eth0`:

```
$ tcpdump -n -i eth0 | grep 192.30.253.112
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
```

`sysctl` reports that forwarding is on:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward 
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3, Linux 4.4.0-112-generic.

What could be the problem? Where can I look to debug this?

Comment: Anyway, this comment is irrelevant to this question, but why you still have the old kernel installed?

Comment: @Vlastimil - for some reason 4.4.0 seems to be default on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (while 4.13.0 is available from the repos as well). It is updated regularly, so I guess that's not that much of a problem.

Comment: @Vlastimil - More complete answer: package `linux-image-virtual` depends on 4.4.0-112, and it is installed by default in LTS, probably to help with upgrades (`apt dist-upgrade` updates package `linux-image-virtual` and pulls in correct `linux-image-*` package automatically).